# What will be the procedure to detect only red colored handwritten digit?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, object-detection, digits

How to detect only red colored handwritten digit by training a cnn model on MNIST dataset? The model will only detect red colored digit from multiple colored digit. What will be the procedure?

I have trained a model by deactivating blue and green channel from RGB. But this procedure is not working.

Comment: Step one: preprocess the image. In your case it might be helpful to filter by red.

Comment: You can use OpenCV's colour filtering to filter red colour: https://pythonprogramming.net/color-filter-python-opencv-tutorial/

Comment: MNIST is a dataset of greyscale images! How are you defining red-colored handwritten digits?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example